# keyup fires before bound textbox value updates

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have a textbox with the text value bound to a model.  The textbox has a KeyUp event.  Here is the xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding VisitorTeamStats.Fouls}">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
               <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding VisitorFoulsKeyUpCmd}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Everything is wired correctly.  Here is what happens.  The initial value of the textbox when you start the application is 0.  When I enter new number, say 8, the OnCommand method registers 0 for the bond value of the textbox in my model.  When I enter another number in the textbox, say a 9, the keyup even fires and the boud value of the textbox in my model is now 8.

So, the keyup event fires BEFORE the bound value of VisitorTeamStats.Fouls updates.  How do I key the bound value to update first, or otherwise pass in the value from the textbox into the keyup event.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without understanding the context of your issue I'm not sure why you need the KeyUp event?  Can you not run the keyUpCommand from the bound field's (Fouls in your case) set method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the triggering of update. Try this code and see what happens:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding VisitorTeamStats.Fouls, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
       <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding VisitorFoulsKeyUpCmd}"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </TextBox>
```

Comment: I tried it.  Did not work.  It would have been cleaner than how I got it to work.  I added a keyup event to update the value.

Comment: it worked on my computer. maybe I could help if I can see more of your code.

Comment: It worked.  I went to update my question and realized this does work.  I didn't see the property change the first time I tried it.  Thanks a bunch!!!